# Why does Regex.IsMatch return wrong values?

Tags: c#, regex

With this code, isMatch is false.

```
var input = "12312345023";
var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(@"^\d{6,}", input);
```

And if input = "", isMatch is true.  Not sure why it seems to be opposite of what it should be.

If I try the same pattern and input [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester) it works as expected.  But when I start a new console app with just that code, isMatch is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> ```
> public static bool IsMatch(
>           string input,
>           string pattern
> )
> ```

Since your parameters are swapped, your pattern is empty. The result will always be true. You need to swap your parameters to get a correct result:

```
var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^\d{6,}");
```

Comment: doh!  of course!  thanks